# ath10k installation

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, atheros

I have exhausted google on how to do this, compounded by being a beginner.

I am trying to install [this module](https://github.com/kvalo/ath/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k).

I have a nice new Acer Nitro (which will be even nicer once I remove dependency on win 8.1), with Atheros Qualcomm QCA61x4 wifi/bluetooth card, which seems to pop up with the same signature `168c:003e` as the QCA6174, so I am hoping this module will work.

I have tried with windows drivers and ndiswrapper but this didn't work for me.

I have also tried upgrading the kernel to 3.19 but that didn't seem to fix it. Now on a FRESH 14.04 install.

- How do I download the appropriate files from github (& where do I save them?)
- Which packages do I need to rebuild the kernel? (I have a fresh 14.04 install)

Comment: I'm just preparing to install on a the same PC. Did you solve this eventually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 users with internet access (e.g. ethernet) should just have to install updates and reboot:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

For those without internet, download the firmware drivers from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/linux-firmware). Choose the latest version for your architecture. For example, version 1.157.5 (newest as of 29/11/16) for amd64 is [here](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/292156147/linux-firmware_1.157.5_all.deb).

Once you have the `.deb` package, install as usual. For our example, it is:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.157.5_all.deb
```

Reboot, and now it should be working.

---

It might be easier to install backports than trying to use github

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/03/13/backports-20150313.tar.xz
tar xvfJ backports-20150313.tar.xz
cd backports-20150313
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

Then reboot when it is finished.  Your wifi is fairly new to Linux so it might not be fully functional even with this

Comment: Thanks,  though this doesn't seem to do the trick. Card still not doing 
anything.
lspci | grep Network gives:
"07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 003e (rev 20)".
modprobe ath10k gives:
"modprobe: FATAL: Module ath10k not found".

Comment: I think the module name is ath10k_pci

Comment: @diablo666 If it doesn't work, please don't "accept" the answer.

Comment: 2016 June update - the wget and intall worked for me on acer aspire e 15 (E5-573G-34QR). Thank you! Had to follow this and the UEFI boot steps at http://askubuntu.com/a/630662/165511

Comment: It works for my Acer Aspire V 17 Nitro with Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4.0-28-generic). Thanks.

Comment: All I needed was a 'modprobe ath10k_pci' on 16.04 ...

Answer (score 15):

I've had a number of issues with my Acer Aspire V17 Nitro Black Edition and Ubuntu 15.10, but I managed to solve the Wi-Fi.  I had to do a combination of things the answers from above, namely:

1. Copy the *QCA6174* directory from https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware into */lib/firmware/ath10k/*.  I already had an older version of *QCA6174* in that directory, so I renamed the old folder to *QCA6174.orig*.
2. Download the file from Comment 2 here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1294263#c2 and save it as */lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin* (backing up the old *board.bin* as *board.bin.orig*)
3. Reboot.

I'm posting this comment from my new internet connection over Wi-Fi.  So far it seems to be working fine.

Comment: I can confirm this. My QCA6147 works after copying the windows firmware to /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6147/hw3.0/board-2.bin and copying the firmware from ath10k-firmware to  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6147/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin

Comment: Step 2 doesn't seem necessary anymore (tested on Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 10):

I had similar problem with my new laptop Asus Aspire V3-371-51 after installing the new Ubuntu (15.10) which has 4.2 kernel (so no backport is needed).

```
$ uname -r
4.2.0-16-generic
```

lspci showed the following data:

```
$ lspci
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
$ lspci -n
02:00.0 0280: 168c:003e (rev 20)
```

Checking dmesg, I realized that in my case the firmware is missing.

```
[    2.360584] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.362523] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-pci-168c:003e:11ad:0804.bin failed with error -2
[    2.362527] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2
[    2.362536] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin failed with error -2
[    2.362538] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to fetch generic board data: -2
[    2.362540] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to fetch board file: -2
[    2.362541] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[    2.362543] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
```

Copying an appropriate firmware from https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/archive/master.zip to `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1` did the trick - after reboot.

BTW I had to create the that path, because only `QCA988X` subdirectory was in `/lib/firmware/ath10k` before.

Comment: But there is no cal-pci.bin file in the kvalo git repository. Did you only copy the 2.1 folder or any other file also ?

Comment: If this doesn't work, rename QCA6174 (if previously existing) and copy the whole QCA6174 folder from the mentioned Github page (both hw2.1 and hw3.0). Then inside both folders  rename firmware-x.bin_WLAN.etc to firmware-x.bin.

Answer (score 9):

Not a complete answer (similar situation - ath10k/QCA6174 on a Fedora 22, 4.0 kernel), but more resources:

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k points to:
https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.

Looking at dmesg, I can get firmware-4.bin loaded (albeit untested), when place at:

```
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1
```

However, I also get:

```
Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
invalid firmware magic
Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-3.bin': -2
```

So something still appears to be missing in this setup. Next step is to rename a long filename firmware-3.bin_xxxxxx to firmware-3.bin

PS (reload ath10k kernel module):

```
sudo rmmod ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe -v ath10k_pci
```

Then take your pick of `iwconfig` or `NetworkManager`.

So the steps to a complete installation are:

1. Download drivers in https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.
2. `sudo cp -r QCA6174 /lib/firmware/ath10k/`
3. `cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1`
4. `sudo cp firmware-5.bin.SW_xxxxxx firmware-5.bin`

   This step may change as driver is developed. `xxxx` and `-5` are evolving.
5. `sudo rmmod ath10k_pci`
6. `sudo modprobe -v ath10k_pci`

After these steps I could connect to a WPA2 WiFi router and everything is working okay in an Acer v5 vn7-591g black nitro.

Comment: In 4. how can you copy

Comment: Wow man, thanks! I can confirm that this is working on OpenSuse Leap 42.1 (kernel 4.4), in a Dell Latitude E5570 (same QCA6174 chip)

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get my Qualcomm Atheros 61x4 running on a ubuntu 15.04 clean install. Actually not for the Lenovo model but for an Acer Aspire VN7 Nitro 791G These are the steps I accomplished:

- install kernel sources: apt-get install linux-headers-(uname -r)
- downloaded the athk master sources from kvalo:

  `git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath.git`
- downloaded the backports tree:

  `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/backports/backports.git`
- built the new backport tree according to the instructions found on linux-wireless: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k/backports
- downloaded the firmware from sumdog and copied it to `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/` :

  (Sorry I am not allowed to post more than two links)
- `wget github.com/sumdog/ath10k-firmware/raw/5faf5bb7c7413f9bbde54cca6fff58e/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin`

  and

  `wget github.com/sumdog/ath10k-firmware/raw/5faf5bb7c7413f9bbde54cca6fff58e/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin`
- created athk10 config file as described in this post before:

  ```
  sudo echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf
  ```
- copied `firmware-4.bin` to `firmware-5.bin` as dmesg claimed about not finding `firmware-5.bin`

Answer (score 4):

Install the LTS 'Wily' enablement stack.  This will give you a more modern kernel, 4.2.  There are numerous improvements in this kernel, and as noted by someone else, it looks like it will support your chipset natively.

[Kernel / LTSEnablementStack | Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Answer (score 3):

After going through all of the other answers I ended up having success with the following process:

My setup is Mint 17.2 (should be the same as Ubuntu 14.04) with kernel 3.16.0-38-generic on Acer v17 Nitro using the QCA6174 firmware

Because I'm on a 3.x Kernel Download and build the backports project per the instructions here (if you have a 4.x kernel it should work without in theory):
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k/backports

- Use the link in those instructions to stable releases "latest backports release" I used backports-4.2.6-1 because that was the latest at this time.

Download the firmware for my setup from the chart on this page QCA6174:
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k/firmware

- This links to the kvalo github that other posts here are referencing

Copy all firmware files for QCA6174 from ath10k-firmware/QCA6174/ to /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174

- Rename all firmware bin files remove everything after .bin
- sudo chmod 755 on all of these files
- sudo chmod +x on all of these files

Reboot.

I think using the latest stable backports project vs some of the ones linked here, combined with setting the permissions correctly was related to making it work.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me except:

```
sudo wget http://www.killernetworking.com/support/K1535_Debian/board.bin -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1/firmware-6.bin_WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00132-QCARMSWP-1 -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
```

Now I finally can use WiFi on Redmibook 13 Ryzen Edition