# Unable to get wireless internet Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, atheros

I've been looking around for hours to find a driver or a solution to get my wifi working on my new laptop *(Acer Aspire V 17 nitro)*.

But without success.

I have a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 Installed,

This is the result i get from `lspci -vnn | grep Network`

> Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)

I have been googling for hours, is there no solution ?

Will I have to get a usb wifi adaptor and get a wifi connection like that ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation  Unfortunately the modules for the QCA6174 are still a bit rough and only provide minimal support, the last I heard was that you could possibly connect to an unsecured network

Comment: Ok, this is really sad news. I love ubuntu but I need wifi. Thanks anyways !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface)

Answer (score 0):

For the QCA6174 probably the easiest thing to do is upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 (you can use the Ubuntu software updater rather than installing 15.10 from scratch) as this has the kernel 4.2 and the [ath10k](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k) firmware

Comment: Tried it out with 15.10 but I still can't get wifi to work.

Comment: using `dmesg` i still get something like: ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware.bin failed with error -2
[    3.719535] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
[    3.719537] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[    3.719538] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)

Comment: Are the ath10k kernel modules loaded (they refer to ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware.bin)? In terminal try: lsmod | grep ath10k. Something like ath, ath_pci, ath10k_core along with mac80211 and cfg80211would be what you're looking for.  If they are loaded try unloading using rmmod and then reload them using modprobe.

Comment: If that doesn't work try downloading the ath10k firmware from the github page listed on [linux wireless](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k/firmware). Copy and paste where the old ath10k folder (you may need to rename a .bin file so that it matches what is supposed to be in the directory-ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware.bin). Again reload the ath10k kernel modules using rmmod and modprobe (or restart your system).