# No WiFi on Lenovo Yoga 3

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I'm using on Xubuntu 14.10 and I have exactly this model: 80J80021US

I've installed the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package, used this command `sudo rfkill unblock all` and also tried to disable `ideapad_laptop` by running `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop`.

Nothing seems to work.

If I don't remove the `ideapad_laptop` I can see the device on the `rfkill list`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I use the command `modprobe -r`, then there's no wifi adapter at all:

```
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I found a post that said that I should add the `wl` module to `/etc/modules`. But then the following is in my log file:

```
[    5.069958] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    5.072260] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Comment: What does `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` say about the wifi

Comment: @Jeremy31 It says: `02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3044]`

Comment: wl will not work for your wifi as yours is the same as in this question  http://askubuntu.com/questions/608381/unable-to-get-wireless-internet-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-802-11ac

Comment: I have the same problem with mine. Everything else about the system runs great (keyboard buttons, touch interfacing, etc.) but the wireless is kaput. So I guess I need an Ethernet-USB adapter to have any shot at fixing this? Or is there any way the drivers can be copied onto the LiveUSB somehow?