# No wireless Ubuntu 15.10 for Lenovo Yoga 3 11

Tags: wireless, 15.10

I got a Lenovo Yoga 3 11 and installed Ubuntu 15.10 trouble is

- no wifi
- no ethernet (computer is too thin)

I've heard this is a very specific bug. After some reading I have a Qualcomm Atheros Device but forget the exact number.  Other questions address the Broadcom case.

After downloading the CD image, I installed a dual boot partition with Windows 10 and Lenovo has the wireless driver for Windows.

Writing this question from my phone will continue to supply more details.

---

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940

[Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface. Atheros [168c:003e] device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface-atheros-168c003e-dev) (solution was to upgrade to 15.10)

[No WiFi on Lenovo Yoga 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608755/no-wifi-on-lenovo-yoga-3)

---

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
```

[image]

---

## ath10k

https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware
[ath10k installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation)

I have no idea what these do or if they are correct

One possible hardware solution is usb ethernet adaptor but guess what? No internet no cd rom so i can't download
http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=86;71;101&PLine=71

[image]

---

```
dpkg -l | grep "linux-firmware"
ii linux-firmware 1.149 all Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @pilot6 this is hard to do from my phone.  One moment please

Comment: You can enable wifi by using the first two commands from my answer. Everything else will be much easier with an internet connection.

Comment: I asked for a bit different command ;-)

Comment: @pilot6 wifi does not work even after modprobe and rfkill

Comment: @chili555 Do you have an Idea?

Comment: Why do you complain about no cd-rom? You can always copy files using a flash drive.

Comment: I suspect the driver lacks the needed firmware. Let's find out which it wants and I will propose a solution involving a flash drive. Please run: `dmesg | grep ath` and post which firmware file it is looking for but not finding. It may be `Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin failed with error -2` or some such, but we need to know the exact details.

Comment: @chili555 please take a look. Indeed its looking for something and not finding it. Not sure

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep "linux-firmware"`

Comment: So chili555's answer worked? That's good, but it is not clear why.

Comment: Any word on this working out of the box on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wireless driver requires firmware that is not installed by default. Please download this file on some other computer and transfer it with a flash drive or similar: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.149.3_all.deb

Transfer it to the Ubuntu computer and drag and drop it to the desktop. Now, on the Ubuntu computer, open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

After it is done, please do:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Your wireless should be working but it might take a reboot.

Comment: I am afraid this will not help. By default Ubuntu 15.10 contains 1.149.2 firmware that contains the same files related to ath10k as 1.149.3.

Comment: +1. But I have no idea why this worked.

Comment: Glad it's working by whatever means!

Answer (score 0):

The wireless adapter is probably blocked by the platform driver.

You can fix it by running

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

This should unblock it until a reboot.

To make it permanent you can run

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

This will permanently disable the platform driver.

A better solution is to report a bug to launchpad by running:

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

and add there output of

```
sudo dmidecode | grep "System Information" -A8
```

If you drop a link to the bug report, I will be able to take care of it.

The issue has been fixed upstream, but it needs to be backported to the current Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: I can't report a bug without Internet.  What do you mean "upstream"?  The most recent 15.10 kernel I can find dates to October

Comment: I mean that in kernel 4.4 it is fixed. Just run the first two commands. That should be fixed.

Comment: I noticed blacklists for `ath-pci` and `bcm43` but not `ideapad_laptop` are those relevant?

Comment: No internet still