# Wireless on Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro 1370 not detected by Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: wireless, lenovo, 19.04

I'm having a lot of trouble getting the wireless adapter on my Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro 1370 Ultrabook working. The OS reports `No Wi-Fi Adapter Found`.

I've installed Ubuntu 19.04.

I've spent several nights going through similar questions, such as

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
[No wireless Ubuntu 15.10 for Lenovo Yoga 3 11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723810/no-wireless-ubuntu-15-10-for-lenovo-yoga-3-11) (I downloaded the deb file for 19.04 and did the same instructions).

When i run the command `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`, the following info is provided about my Broadcom adapater: [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)

This is a bit tricky as this laptop has no Ethernet port or CD drive.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to get this done. As I mentioned in the orig post, the problem was that I had no way of accessing the Internet to run `apt-get` commands, as the laptop has no Ethernet port.

Or so I thought. I completely forgot about tethering a phone using a USB cable. I tethered my Android phone and was able to follow the instructions in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/773914/956935).

That applied to my Yoga 3 Pro because, as stated in my question, I have a Broadcom adapter.

Hope this helps others who find themselves in my predicament.

Comment: This worked great!