# Not able to connect to Wireless in Ubuntu 15.10 with laptop Acer Aspire V 15

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, acer

I have a new laptop (Acer Aspire V 15) and ubuntu is not connecting to the wireless. At first it wasn't recognizing the wireless, so I installed the driver. Now it detects the wireless networks available, but when I enter the wifi key it doesn't connect.

It's only working with ethernet.

Will I have to uninstall and re-install the driver? If so, can anyone walk me through it? Otherwise I won't know how to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: if you have difficulty to follow my response below (not sure how good you are in linux) here someone with the same wifi device solved the issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation/607982

Comment: The post you suggest was what I used when I first realised wifi wasn't working. I didn't install Ubuntu myself (GRUB problems). So I will probably have to remove both. But how do I do that?

Comment: that is basic of linux you should learn my friend. to remove a module you do "modprobe -r module_name" by installing drivers it will automatically add modules into kernel and to blacklist the module http://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules. about the driver you installed, you remove it and reinstall the same way you installed.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to provide preliminary data and details in order for anyone to help you here. No one has the crystal ball so they don't know what you have.

Pls post the output of the following commands (just run it in your shell):

```
 lspci -nn | grep -i net;lspci -k;sudo lshw -C network;lsmod;iwconfig;ifconfig;sudo iwlist scan;uname -r -m;cat /etc/network/interfaces;nm-tool;sudo rfkill list
```

==============

Thanks for providing the data.

So this is your wireless devise

```
 03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device 0804
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

And these are modules loaded to kernel for such device:

```
 ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
 ath9k_hw              471040  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
 ath                    32768  4 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath10k_core,ath9k_hw
 mac80211              733184  2 ath9k,ath10k_core
 cfg80211              548864  5 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211,ath10k_core
```

As you can see there are 2 different versions and they are conflicting with each other of course (kernel doesn't know which one to use exactly unless you don't take one of them off).

So I am not sure what drive you have installed. If you remember the version of drive and kernel module you installe then all you have to do is to remove the previously installed kernel modules and blacklist them in order to make sure they don't load again during the boot time.

Alternative, if you don't know which one you installed and which one was already there, I'd suggest to clean all of the moduls and re-install the new one. but you still need to blacklist the old one because it will load after reboot of the system again.

As you can see from the snippet here:

```
  wlp3s0    Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 28:28:5D:F3:40:48
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"ZyXEL_4048"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master


 0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

your wireless is working perfectly but as I said the modules are conflicting with each other, so you need to remove the oldest one.

Comment: I've pasted the result here. pastebin.com/nxn8hj9r  Thank you for your help!