# no wifi with 16.04 on dual boot laptop

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 16.04

I can't get my wifi to work on my laptop dual boot W10 / U16.04

Apologies for the post formating mess I really don't understand how to do it right.

Also I am really new to Ubuntu, I posted all these reports because I found them in other posts but I don't understand what all this means so if you can help, please don't hesitate to "explain like I'm 5" !

- Secure boot is disabled
- sudo lshw -C network result :

  ```
  -network DISABLED    
     description: Wireless interface
     product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
     vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
     logical name: wlp7s0
     version: 32
     serial: 30:52:cb:17:6d:6f
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
     resources: irq:130 memory:64000000-641fffff

  *-network

     description: Ethernet interface
     product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
     logical name: enp8s0
     version: 15
     serial: 30:65:ec:8c:30:ae
     size: 1Gbit/s
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
     resources: irq:125 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:64204000-64204fff memory:64200000-64203fff
  ```
- lspci result :
      lspci
      00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)

  ```
  00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)

  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)

  00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)

  00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPSS I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)

  00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPSS I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)

  00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)

  00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)

  00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)

  00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)

  00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)

  00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)

  00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)

  00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)

  01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)

  07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)

  08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
  ```
- dmsg (part of it, I though it was relevant) :

  ```
   ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:07:00.0.bin failed with error -2

  [    4.101045] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2

  [    4.101047] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2

  [    4.183309] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin failed with error -2

  [    6.303701] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0807) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 1 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad

  [   23.026402] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

  [   29.026593] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

  [   34.338591] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

  [   40.338766] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

  [   56.258875] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set tx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3

  [   59.259040] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11

  [   65.259136] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

  [   70.567077] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

  [   76.567181] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

  [   91.182668] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

  [   97.173662] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

  [  102.485792] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set tx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3

  [  105.484591] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11

  [  111.485134] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

  [  126.159205] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set tx-chainmask: -11, req 0x3

  [  129.160032] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to set arp ac override parameter: -11

  [  135.161492] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

  [  140.470451] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11

  [  146.471285] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)

  [  161.169183] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
  ```
- rfkill list all :

  ```
  0: hci0: Bluetooth

  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no

  1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN

  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no

  2: phy0: Wireless LAN

  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
  ```

Comment: Do you have any other way accessing internet, do you have a android mobile with internet and usb cable?

Comment: I am currently using an ethernet cable so yes, I can access internet on my laptop

Comment: add the output of `sudo rfkill list all`

Comment: Added at the end of my post.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you are using

Comment: 16.04 and I did an update when I plugged the ethernet in just to be sure everything is up to date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ath10k installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation) – you seem to be missing the device firmware files.

Comment: But before you try that, did you install the `linux-firmware` package? It has a `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174` directory with the files that the driver is looking for in vain.

Answer (score 0):

First you reboot your computer and then,

Update your computer with following command:

`sudo apt-get update && dist-upgrade`

> https://packages.debian.org/sid/firmware-atheros
>
> https://packages.debian.org/sid/initramfs-tools

Download these two packages and install them using dpkg command,
so your command should look like this:

`sudo dpkg -i initramfs-tools_0.125_all.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i firmware-atheros_20160110-1_all.deb`

after running these above two mentioned commands,your wifi should work, if not try rebooting once.

Comment: I get erros when trying to install the packages :
> dpkg: regarding initramfs-tools_0.125_all.deb containing initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools breaks upstart
  upstart (version 1.13.2-0ubuntu21) is present and installed.

> dpkg: error processing archive initramfs-tools_0.125_all.deb (--install):
 installing initramfs-tools would break upstart, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools_0.125_all.deb

Comment: you try this i'm not sure how to use this command because right now i'm ain't in system which uses apt/dpkg as package manager. Type this command `sudo dpkg -iB initramfs-tools_0.125_all.deb ` and `sudo dpkg -i firmware-atheros_20160110-1_all.deb` if that didn't work try `-B` instead of `-iB` in case of first command, if you get similar type of command then once you try the second command with `-iB` instead of `-i`, if still problem persists you make a comment here by showing errors.