# No WiFi Networks detected on my Alienware 17 R3 with Killer Wireless-AC 1535 card

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, atheros

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Alienware 17 R3, which comes with Killer Wireless-AC 1535 WiFi card. The WiFi hardware seems to be detected but no WiFi hotspots are being detected.

I learnt somewhere that updating to the latest kernel would fix the problem. The kernel verison according to `uname -r` is 4.4.0-22-generic. Is a more recent version of kernel required?

Any help regarding this would greately help me since I will have to start my development asap and Linux is the go-to platform where I work.

Thanks

**Edit**: Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)

Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]

Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Hi, I have added the requested output. Please guide me further

Comment: This is a firmware issue. You can search for an answer regarding `[168c:003e]`. For 16.04 you do not need any drivers, they are already in kernel, but you may need firmware.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/691563/167850

Comment: @Pilot6  Is [this](http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux/20-killer-wireless-ac-in-linux-ubuntu-debian) the firmware you are talking about? The board.bin file?

Comment: I am not quite sure. You'd better copy them all.

Comment: That page is over 6 months old, better off using linux-firmware from the duplicate post.  Kalle has made changes and added a board-2.bin since then

Comment: This worked!. Thanks! Updating the Linux firmware to 1.158 worked. Sweet.  My development work would have gone for a toss without this! I have been trying to make this work from days, and nope, nothing worked. One more question though. I keep getting "Booting in insecure mode" when I boot up Ubuntu, though I have enabled secure boot  in BIOS.  Any fix for this?