# Getting ath10k error on fresh boot of Ubuntu (Qualcomm Atheros wireless)

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, firmware

Trying to step up dual boot on my Windows machine.  I'm getting an error about firmware.  I've chased a bunch of leads with no real solution.

From [REF](https://askubuntu.com/q/607707)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo reboot
```

But I can't even get to a terminal before installation. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you try the command line interface by `Ctrl+Alt+F1` `(or F2 or 3 and so on F7`  at this stage.

Comment: Where will that take me ? to a console/terminal to run apt get etc?  what if I don't have drivers to download?

Comment: Does trying to boot an Ubuntu 16.10 ISO result in the same issue?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I'll try that tonight! Good Idea.

Comment: I don't think it is wireless related but I am sure that Ubuntu 16.10 has the firmware needed on the ISO even though there has never been a /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin as it doesn't exist even in [linux-firmware-next](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0)

Comment: you were right @jeremy31