# 16.04 unable to authenticate to wifi

Tags: wireless

Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an Acer Aspire S and everything's working great except the wifi. I can connect to open hotspots, but when I authenticate to my WPA2 router at home it fails.

This is with an Atheros QCA6174...

```
% lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0807]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

% dmesg | grep -e ath10 -e wlan
[    7.215916] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    7.509020] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    7.509034] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    7.510267] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    7.510269] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    7.513370] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0807
[    7.513371] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    7.513875] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
[    7.579414] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 6fc88fe7
[    9.734242] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    9.826346] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Never had any problem with connecting with my other Ubuntu systems. Here's the modprob...

```
[   55.988872] wlp1s0: authenticated
[   55.989002] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   55.989004] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   55.995359] wlp1s0: associate with 00:24:7b:64:77:bc (try 1/3)
[   55.998581] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 00:24:7b:64:77:bc (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   56.001232] wlp1s0: associated
[   56.001280] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[   59.456829] wlp1s0: deauthenticated from 00:24:7b:64:77:bc (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
[   63.649930] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
```

Seems it authenticates successfully but then deauthenticates right after? Tried replacing my /lib/firmware/ath10k as mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/a/718430/717711 but that caused my wireless to stop working entirely so reverted those changes.

Unfortunately I'm now a bit stumped. Help appreciated!

Comment: I know it seems extremely simple but have you tried rebooting, or restarting the network-manager?

Comment: Yup. Tried rebooting several times, 'sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart', and restarting the network-manager.

Comment: `sudo network-manager restart`? Or did the answer below fulfill your question?

Comment: Nope, as I mentioned restarted network-manager and the below didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. WPA authentication works with other routers, just not the router I have at home. To be clear...

- WPA with other routers works.
- WPA with my home router works using Windows.
- WPA with my home router works with other Ubuntu systems.
- Only trouble is with Ubuntu's Atheros firmware and this particular router.

Odd, but easy to fix. It's an old router anyway. :)