# Wifi is not connected automatically in my dell inspiron 15 5570

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, drivers, wireless

I am using dell inspiron 15 5570 laptop. I have windows10 and ubuntu 14.04LTS(dual os). Wifi is not connected automatically , enable Wifi option is not listed when clicking wifi icon. In windows 10, wifi is connected automatically and work fine.

If I connect wifi dongle, available wifi's are listed and I can able to connect. But if I remove wifi dongle, listed wifi names and enable wifi option is not shown in the list. I have installed broadcam and b43 driver.But it does not help.

**My terminal output for the command.**

```
~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)

Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:1810]

Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

 ~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no

 ~$ dmesg | grep ath

 [   15.367226]  [<ffffffff8107d776>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
 [   15.367228]  [<ffffffff8107d86a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
 [   15.367328]  [<ffffffff817f6f36>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
 [   15.696763] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
 [   15.697629] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8  irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
 [   15.934442] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
  [   15.934449] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   15.934450] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   15.934454] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
[   15.934455] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
[   15.934458] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
[   15.934459] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
[   15.934463] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
[   15.934464] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
 [   15.934467] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
 [   15.934468] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
[   15.934469] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files   (-2)
 [   15.934470] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
```

Comment: Let's see what wireless device you have. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Let's see if the wireless switch or key combination is set to enable wireless. Please edit to include: `rfkill list all` and next let's see if there are any clues in the logs: `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: You have used the incorrect command searching the logs - you searched for 'path' but should have searched for 'ath'

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/639196/283721) which deals with a problem with your wireless card, and the older linux kernels

Answer (score 0):

You need firmware! With a working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
cd /tmp
sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.