# Wifi in not starting

Tags: wireless

I have tried what most the suggestion provided in this forum. I am posting the log. Please help me out to sort this out.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/26326520/

Comment: May we also see a paste of: `dmesg | grep ath` Thanks.

Comment: dmesg o/p : https://paste.ubuntu.com/26329816/

Comment: Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/990283/wifi-is-not-connected-automatically-in-my-dell-inspiron-15-5570/990373#990373