# ath10k firmware issues

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, firmware

It looks like many people have firmware issues with Qualcomm Atheros devices on Ubuntu. I'm one of them. It used to work, then the power reset on my router, and now it doesn't. The output of the [ubiquitous network debugging script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180) can be found at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lbordowitz/13a90ccd115bf761fc37e890fb4dfe8a).

I can connect to the LEDE wireless network, but my ping to the gateway times out. I have full control of the wireless router. The line of most concern to me is this dmesg output:

```
[    3.154149] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ath10k installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation)