# Verbose details shown during boot of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, gnome, customization

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  My system boots properly and works fine, but during boot, I can see the verbose details about what is happening during the boot process:

[image: Screenshot of boot]

Is this supposed to happen?  Can it be changed?

Comment: It's showing the boot text because your modem driver firmware isn't loading.

Comment: How to fix it?? Please help me out!!

Comment: Try reinstalling `linux-firmware`. `sudo apt-get reinstall linux-firmware`. Report back.

Comment: Will it work??

Comment: It shows unable to locate package...

Comment: Nimath, Everything is working fine almost perfect but this boot screen annoys me Everytimee....

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with loading `ath10k` kernel driver. Here is possible solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation

Comment: Then try `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a GRUB setting.

Open your terminal and run the following to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and make sure it says:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

- `quiet` means no verbose output.
- `splash` means show the splash screen (the Ubuntu logo).

Save the changes using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and close nano using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Update GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.